# Weird functionality when adding views to custom collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

While adding contents to a customer view cell, I am getting unexpected functionality.

Here is the code, and then I will explain what I have found.

Controller code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let bedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BedCell", for: indexPath) as! BedCollectionViewCell
    
    bedCell.cellsBedModel = cottageModel!.bedsList[indexPath.item]
    bedCell.setupBedCell()
    
    return bedCell
    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    let columns: CGFloat = 2
    
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat
    
    let widthOfCollection = collectionView.bounds.width
    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let spaceBetweenCells = flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * (columns - 1)
    
    let adjustedWidth = widthOfCollection - spaceBetweenCells
    
    width = floor(adjustedWidth / columns)
    height = width
    
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    
}
```

Custom cell code:

```
import UIKit

class BedCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var cellsBedModel: Bed?

//view objects to place in the cell
var bedImageView = UIImageView()
var bedSizeLabel = UILabel()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    layer.cornerRadius = 10
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    
}

func setupBedCell() {
    
    //create the cell's bed image and place it in the image view
    let bedImage = UIImage(systemName: "bed.double")
    bedImageView.image = bedImage
    bedImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    
    contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
    
    bedSizeLabel.text = String(describing: cellsBedModel!.size)
    bedSizeLabel.textAlignment = .center
    bedSizeLabel.textColor = .black
    bedSizeLabel.backgroundColor = .gray
    
    //add the view objects to the cell's content view
    
    //set the cell's content constraints
    setImageConstraints()
    setLabelConstraints()
    
    
}

func setImageConstraints() {
    self.contentView.addSubview(bedImageView)
    //bedImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //bedImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    //bedImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    //bedImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
}

func setLabelConstraints() {
    self.contentView.addSubview(bedSizeLabel)
    //bedSizeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //bedSizeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    //bedSizeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    //bedSizeLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    
    //removes all children views from the cell before reusing a cell
    for cell in self.contentView.subviews {
        cell.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
}

}
```

Basically, with this code right now, nothing shows in the cells for some reason even though I added them to the content view. BUT, I can see in the debugger of the view hierarchy that the cells are generated and the right size:

[image]

Now, when I uncomment the lines of code for the autolayout constraints, the image and label now appears BUT the cells shrink to match these views:

[image]

With collection views and cells, I am still new to swift/iOS and trying to understand why this is happening. From my understanding, the autolayout constraints are set on the image views inside of the cell content view, so shouldn't they grow to match the cell content view rather than shrink the cell content view? Also, why do the views (image and label) now show in the cells content view until constraints are added? This is unclear to me. If anyone knows a solution I may be missing and why this is happening it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you create a tiny project where you can reproduce the issue and share it? It will be great to quickly debug the issue.

Comment: Try setting `Estimated Size` to `None` in the storyboard for the collection view

Comment: @aheze that was it, man being new to iOS it is hard to keep track of all these things. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Np, I had this problem a while ago too